# How to reformat a string in python?

Tags: python

Right now I have a string in the form `xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com` and I want to strip off the @zzz.com so that it comes out as `xxx@yyy.com`.

Comment: `'@'.join('xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com'.split('@')[:-1])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
"xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com".replace("@zzz.com", "")
```

If you know it will always be "@zzz.com".

Otherwise, you could try:

```
data = "xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com"
if data.count("@") == 2:
    data = data.rsplit('@', 1)[0]
```

Or, more generally:

```
data = "xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com@___.com"
if data.count("@") > 1:
    data = data.rsplit('@', data.count("@")-1)[0]
```

You can learn more about the string methods I have used at [Python : String Methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: thanks. is there any documentation for each of the methods that you use here?

Comment: @cfarm54 You can find it in the usual place for documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com'.rpartition('@')[0]
'xxx@yyy.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com"
string = "@".join(string.split("@")[:2])
```

Simple way to do the job. I don't think it's very safe though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 19 2010, 21:55:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('@[^@.]*\.com$', '', 'xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com')
'xxx@yyy.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com"

print string[0:string.rfind('@')]
```

can help you

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Please check it.

```
st='xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com'  
print st  
newstr=st[0:st.rfind('@')]  
print newstr
```

Idea is to use rfind and strip find the @ symbol from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this code is too much for the task, but here ya go.

```
data = "xxx@yyy.com@zzz.com"

def cleaner(email):
   counter = 0
   result = ''
   for i in data:
      if i == "@":
        counter += 1
      if counter == 2:
        break
      result += i
   return result

data = cleaner(data)

data = 'xxx@yyy.com'
```

Just pass the data to the cleaner function.  For example:  cleaner(data) will return the correct answer.

edit:  what gribbler posted is 1000x better than this...lol  I am still learning :)

```
data.rpartition('@')[0]
```